# Center vertically floating divs

Tags: html, css, css-float

I need to center vertically floating divs and images to their container. I tried many ways but none works fine.

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybbV2.png)

http://codepen.io/catapanoa/pen/ygaKLy?editors=1100

```
      <div class="leftWrapper">
        <div class="title">
           Title 1<br>
           <span class="subtitle">Subtitle 1</span>
         </div>
      </div>
.
.
.
```

Comment: can you provide more details ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to center content vertically

```
.vert-center {
    margin-top: 50%;
    translate: transform-y(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrap { position:relative; }
.center {
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
right:0;
left:0;
bottom:0;
display:flex;
position:absolute;
text-align:center;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}



<div class="wrap">

    <div class="center">

        <div>

            <h1>Title</h1>

            <span>span</span>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.title 
{
  border: 1px solid green;
   position: relative;
   top:50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```